# Combining dataframes with same column but different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge df1 and df2, both have different lengths. The intersection on key column needs to be such that the output table has the values from df2 for every corresponding key as the values within the key column are repeating.

df1

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 14 |
| 4 | 14 |

df2

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |

output

| key | value | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | a |
| 1 | 5 | a |
| 2 | 9 | b |
| 3 | 11 | c |
| 4 | 14 | d |
| 4 | 14 | d |

I'm trying
output = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'key', right_on = 'key')
But it's creating extra rows.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I believe the output is ok. What are the extra rows that you notice? Since `df1` has keys `1` and `4` twice, then those will appear twice as well in the final result, after the merge. May be, if it would help, you could try a `pd.merge(df1,df2,on='KEY').drop_duplicates()` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on='KEY', how='left').rename(columns={'VALUE_x':'VALUE','VALUE_y':'VALUE'})
```

Prints:

```
    KEY VALUE VALUE
0   1   5     a
1   1   5     a
2   2   9     b
3   3   11    c
4   4   14    d 
5   4   14    d
```